# Move MS Word cursor via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA and I am developing an Excel VBA that builds an Word DOC from XLS data. I am having trouble to make automatically type the text into the right line of the Word doc. Here is what I tried:

- Created an "AutoNew" macro in Word to move the cursor to a specific bookmark when the file is opened. It works when you manually open the .dotm file, but does not work using the Excel VBA to open the same file. The AutoNew macro also does not seem to work if you use the .docm format;
- Set SendKeys command which worked, but it is a bad option as I need to make sure Word window is selected, otherwise is sends the keys anywhere else.

I need to make VBA start writing the text in an specific line of the Word DOC.
Below is the Excel VBA code, I appreiciate any help!

```
Sub CreateWordDoc_Click()
    Dim objWord 
    Dim objDoc 
    Dim objSelection 
    Dim text As String
       
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\mywordtemplate.dotm" 
    objWord.Visible = True 
    
    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection 
    
'The below will run the Ctrl+END SendKeys, which I want to avoid
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    
    Application.SendKeys ("^{END}")
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
          
    For Each cell In Range("MyData!A1:A9")
        text = text & cell.Value & Chr(13)
    Next cell

      
    For Each cell In Range("MyData!D1:D4")
        text = text & cell.Value & Chr(13)
    Next cell
    
    For Each cell In Range("MyData!G1:G6")
        text = text & cell.Value & Chr(13)
    Next cell
       
    objSelection.TypeText (text) 
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA is single threaded. Any code in the Word document won't run when accessing it this way. You would have to copy the code from the Word doc to the Excel doc and just run it there.

Comment: Have you looked into just using Mail Merge in Word? That is the preeminent method of getting Excel data into a Word document. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Comment: Using the `Selection` object, whether in Word or Excel, is a really bad idea for many reasons. If you do your research you will find many examples on SO that show you how to insert text at bookmarks. Just do a search for "[vba] [ms-word] bookmark"